# colSums if another column is true (for stacked barplot)

Tags: r

I have:

```
$ Facebook       : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 ...
$ YouTube        : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
...
$ Subscribed     : int  0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 ...
```

If I use `sourceTotals = colSums(sources[c(2:13)])`, I'll generate a data frame with totals for each service.

How can I generate something along the lines of:

```
Service      Subscribed NotSubscribed Total
Facebook     50         50            100
YouTube      10         235           245
```

(I will then try to generate a stacked barplot based on the new data frame)

I tried things such as `sourceTotals = data.frame(colSums(ifelse((sources[c(2:13)]+sources[15])>2, 1, 0)), colSums(ifelse((sources[c(2:13)]+sources[15])>2, 1, 0)), colSums(sources[c(2:13)]))` but that deosn't seem to be it.

Thanks!

---

Solution based on Karolis' answer:

```
myData = sources[c(2:14)]

sL = rep("none", nrow(myData))
for(i in 1:ncol(myData)-1) {
    sL[as.logical(myData[,i])] <- colnames(myData)[i]
}

sM = addmargins(table(sL, Subscribed=as.logical(myData$Subscribed)), 2)

library(reshape2)
sM1 = melt(sM[,c(1:2)])

colnames(sM1) = c("Source", "Subscribed", "Users")

ggplot(sM1, aes(x=Source, y=Users, fill=Subscribed)) + geom_bar(stat="identity") + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))
```

Comment: Sorry, I cannot wrap my head around the data. You have one "Subscribed" value for both Facebook and YouTube and all "..." ?

Comment: Yes... FB and YouTube are sources of a customer. Subscribed indicates whether they became a customer. Only one of FB and YT can be a 1 then, but but both FB and Subscribed can be true, for example. Does that make it clearer?

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example

Comment: `structure(list(Google = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L), Chrome.Store = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L), Facebook = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Subscribed = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L)), .Names = c("Google", "Chrome.Store", "Facebook", 
"Subscribed"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be easy if you convert your data to a more convenient form. You can replace all your 0/1 for groups into a single factor:

```
Groups <- rep("none", nrow(myData))
for(i in 1:ncol(myData)-1) {
    Groups[as.logical(myData[,i])] <- colnames(myData)[i]
}

Groups
[1] "Google"       "Google"       "Google"       "Google"       "Chrome.Store" "Google"
```

After that it's this easy:

```
addmargins(table(Groups, Subscribed=as.logical(myData$Subscribed)), 2)
              Subscribed
Groups         FALSE TRUE Sum
  Chrome.Store     1    0   1
  Google           4    1   5
```